# IntentFilter for "com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" doesn't work on Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-7.0-nougat, android-image-capture

Added this code in Manifest

```
 <receiver
           android:name=".CameraImageReceiver"
           android:enabled="true">
           <intent-filter android:priority="10000">

           <action android:name="com.android.camera.NEW_PICTURE" />


         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
```

Then I have below code in CameraImageReceiver class:

```
public class CameraImageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String TAG = CameraImageReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;
    private String imgName = "";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.mContext = context;
        Log.d("", "action: " + intent.getAction());
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "imageCaptured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("", "image url: " + intent.getData());
}
}
```

This works totally fine to receive intent in broadcast but this is not working for Android 7.0 because they have restricted this intent filter from background [here is ref.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/background-optimization.html#media-broadcasts.)
Is there any workaround possible to track the camera image event listener for android 7.0???? Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: i seen the article , please read it carefully

Comment: they have an alternate solution for it

Comment: @quicklearner yes we implemented that now but that works if app is running in background. If app is killed completely then it gives error while rescheduleJob as that doesn't have a context to reschedule the job. we even solved that through a service running in background but now the problem is how to make sure service is always running inspite of app crash,, low memory, or in any other circumstances..Here is my another question, different from above though that How do we make sure that service keep running till app is installed in device?? thanks for help..

Comment: i am also having same problem. Could please share some code

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036523/broadcast-receivers-not-working-in-android-6-0-marshmallow